# How can I access gedit's settings menu in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gedit

I updated to 18.04 and I cannot find gedit's settings menu anymore. There's a "hamburger" menu at the top right corner, but it doesn't contain anything useful. How can I set the tab width, enable line numbers etc..?

Answer (score 4):

With gedit in focus, you should see it up in the activities bar, separate from gedit's window. Click to open the drop down menu, and you will find Preferences.

Comment: Right, thanks! :) I had the editor on a second screen that doesn't have the bar, only launcher.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065944/1210606), "Settings" are located under `Preferences` button which can be found in the **top bar application menu** which is (by default) on the top of the screen.

However, if one has additional screens/monitors they might not be able to see this bar there, so one must look at his primary screen/monitor. This is the answer.

If you find this a nuisance, I can recommend Gnome shell extension [Multi Monitor Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) which solved this for me as it allows top panel to be used on all the screens/monitors.